# Can Googlebot crawl JavaScript charts?

Tags: seo, googlebot, javascript, graphics

I am thinking of using Google Charts API to generate client-side charts on my website.

However, my concern is whether Googlebot (for search) will be able to recognize the data?

Comment: What do you mean by "recognize the data"?   Google doesn't deal in "data".   Google uses words.    Charts and images can enhance the page for users but they don't need to be processed by Googlebot for web search ranking purposes.

Comment: I understand images don't give much information other than the alt text (and caption) to google bots. But, the interactive charts (I am using google charts API) process table of data and construct charts through ajax-JSON request and response. Will Googlebot able to see the underlying data (maybe in the form of words) that went into the creation of the charts? (I may be missing something here. Sorry, I am a terrible technical guy.)

Comment: But data isn't words.   Numbers don't mean much to a search engine.  Charts generally very little indexable information: axis, labels, keys. and titles.

Comment: If you use "fetch and render as Google" from Google Search Console, does Googlebot render your chart including any words on it?

Answer (score 2):

Google can crawl Javascript, and it often crawls it perfectly. But there are many instances when Googlebot doesn't understand the Javascript on your site. The more simplistic your code is, the more likely it is that Googlebot can crawl it.

Your best bet is to work on some demo experiments within your charts API and publish them as a test. Run your test page through Google's fetch and render system in Search console, as well as Google's mobile friendly test. If your charts render properly in both versions, it is highly likely that Googlebot can understand your javascript and see the charts. Though it is not guaranteed. If the charts don't render properly in both of those Google tools, then you can experiment with your code to see if Googlebot can render your corrections.